# Dimension free gram matrix inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, matrix-decomposition, linear-regression

Let $\{x_i\}_{i = 1}^n$ be $n$ vectors of $d$ dimesnions.
We stack each $x_i$ as a row vector to form a matrix $X$ of dimension $\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$
Let $\{y_i\}_{i = 1}^n$ be scalars (say all are $1$) and these are stacked to form a matrix $Y$ of dimension $\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$
We compute the following inner product
$$Y^TX(X^TX+ \lambda I)^{-2}X^TY$$
where $\lambda \gt 0$.

Can we show that this seems that does not grow at an order of $n$.

Experimantally it appears so
For $d = 3$ and $n$ running from $1$ to $1000$ we have
[image: inner product vs n]

For $d = 10$ we have
[image]

and for $d=100$ we have[image]

So it seems that for $n$ much greater than $d$ it seems that the hunch is correct.

Any idea on how to proceed.

Thanks

EDIT 1: Here is a proof that $$Y^TX(X^TX+ \lambda I)^{-1}X^TY$$
is $O(n)$

Let $X = U\Sigma V^T$ Then $$Y^TX(X^TX+ \lambda I)^{-1}X^TY = Y^T U \Sigma (\Sigma^T\Sigma + \lambda I)^{-1}\Sigma^T U^TY$$. Now we can note that diagonal elements of $\Sigma (\Sigma^T\Sigma + \lambda I)^{-1}\Sigma^T$ is less than 1. Therefore
$$Y^T U \Sigma (\Sigma^T\Sigma + \lambda I)^{-1}\Sigma^T U^TY \leq Y^T UU^T Y$$
which is less than $n\|Y\|^2_\infty$

My hunch is that $Y^TX(X^TX+ \lambda I)^{-2}X^TY$ will be less than $d\|Y\|^2_\infty$. This is easy if $X^T X$ is diagonal. But is it true for general.

EDIT 2: This is another line of thought I was having,
$$Y^TX(X^TX+ \lambda I)^{-2}X^TY \leq n\|Y\|^2_\infty tr(XX^T) tr ((X^TX)^{-2})$$
Now $tr(XX^T) = O(n)$. If I can say $tr ((X^TX + \lambda I)^{-2})$ is $O(n^{-2})$ Then I can be done. But is this true?

EDIT 3: So this is a line of thought from the previous update
Let $\lambda_1,...\lambda_d$ be the eigenvalues of $X^TX + \lambda I$.
Then the eigen values of $(X^TX + \lambda I)^{-2}$ are $\frac{1}{\lambda_1^2},...\frac{1}{\lambda_d^2}$. So we we have the following,
$$\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_d = O(n)$$,$\lambda_1,...\lambda_d$ are strictly positive.
So we can have $$\lambda_1^2 + \cdots + \lambda_d^2 = O(n^2)$$.

Can we write from this step $$\frac{1}{\lambda_1^2}+ \cdots +\frac{1}{\lambda_d^2} = O(1/n^2)$$?

EDIT 4: I can show that $$\frac{1}{\lambda_1^2}+ \cdots +\frac{1}{\lambda_d^2} = \Omega(1/n^2)$$

$$\frac{1}{\lambda_1^2}+ \cdots +\frac{1}{\lambda_d^2} \geq \frac{d^2}{\lambda_1^2 + \cdots + \lambda_d^2}$$ by AM-HM inequality which is $\Omega(1/n^2)$.

So we have $trace((X^TX + \lambda I)^{-2})$ of the order $\Omega(1/n^2)$. Therefore $$Y^TX(X^TX+ \lambda I)^{-2}X^TY = O(n^2)\Omega(1/n^2)$$

Are my calculations correct? Can we have anything from here?

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: To show $Y^TX(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-2}X^TY$ is independent of $n$

Comment: It seems that you say that $\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2}{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2)^2}$ is and isn't of the order of $n$ in the scalar case, maybe you want to fix that. In the meantime, what kind of dependence on $n$ are you talking about ? in Average maybe ?

Comment: @P.Quinton My hunch is $\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2}{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2)^2}$ is not an order of $n$

Comment: @rostader If I understand well your question, you want to prove that  $$Y^TX(X^TX+ \lambda I)^{-\color{red}{2}}X^TY$$
 is independent of $n$?
$$$$
In your edit, you provided an information that $$Y^TX(X^TX+ \lambda I)^{-\color{red}{1}}X^TY = \mathcal{O}(n)$$

Comment: Yes exactly. I thought I will show my work

Comment: Nitpicky/minor feedback on the visuals - would recommend using a single color for the graphed data, so it doesn't look like there's a third variable involved. [Also maybe smaller points, or alpha, so that the density is visually clearer.] Looks like you might be using matplotlib, in which case you could say for example `plt.scatter(x, y, c="k", s=2, alpha=0.3)`. --- but good job building out numerical experiments! IMO that's an undervalued skill in mathematics.

Comment: @rostader Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see the [guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: @soupless I hope this makes more sense